# Determine individual distribution when knowing joint distribution of $2$ random variables X and Y

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

I have the joint distribution of $2$ random variables $X$ and $Y$. Here:
[image]

How can I determine the distribution of $X$ and the distribution of $Y$ knowing this?

I have tried using the following approach:
\begin{align*}
P\{X = 1 \ \cap \ Y = -3\}=0.2 &\iff  P\{X=1\} P\{Y=-3\} = 0.2 \\
P\{X = 1 \ \cap \ Y = 2\}=\,? &\iff  P\{X=1\} P\{Y=2\} =\,? \\
P\{X = 1 \ \cap \ Y = 4\}=0.2 &\iff  P\{X=1\}  P\{Y=4\} = 0.2\\
&\,\;\;\dotsb\\
P\{X = 3 \ \cap \ Y = -3\}=0.05 &\iff  P\{X=3\}  P\{Y=-3\} = 0.05 \\
&\,\;\;\dotsb\\
P\{X = 3 \ \cap \ Y = 4\}=0.0.5 &\iff  P\{X=3\}P\{Y=4\} = 0.05\\
\end{align*}

And then try to extract the each probability in part. Is this the right way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the marginal distribution since you know the sum over the possible values should be one. 
\begin{array}{r|c|c|c|l}
&-3&2&4&\\\hline
1&0.2&?&0.2&?+0.4\\\hline
3&0.3&0.05&0.05&0.4\\\hline
&0.5&?+0.05&0.25&1
\end{array}

So, we have
$$(.2+.3)+(?+.05)+(.2+.05) = 1$$
This gives that $? = .2$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Related to this exercises is the follwing question: "Are $X$ and $Y$ independent variables?" And the answer would be no (?) Since$ P\{X = x_i \cap  Y=y_j\} \neq P\{X = x_i\} * P\{Y=y_i\}$

Comment: Yes, but I think you have to be specific. Give an example, like show that $P(X = 3,Y = -3)\neq P(X = 3)P(Y = -3)$.

Answer (score 1):

Apply that:$$\sum_{x\in\{1,3\}}\sum_{y\in\{-3,2,4\}}P(X=x,Y=y)=1$$

All terms on LHS are known except for one, which can be found on base of this equality.